# Where is my database file in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to SQLite database in Android and I want know where is my database file (.db)is created .
below is part of my code

```
package com.navigationsystem;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="db";
    public static final String NODE_ID="nodeID";
    //public static final String VALUE="value";

    public static final String CHILD_ID="childID";
    public static final String PARENT_ID="parentID";



    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE constants (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,title TEXT, value REAL);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE nodes( nodeID CHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY );");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE edges( childID CHAR(1) NOT NULL, parentID CHAR(1) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(childID,parentID) );");


    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        ......................
```

please give me details.

thanks.

Comment: I don't see any paths that you are setting as destination of your database file..but as a default place Android is storing the db files in `data/data/your.application.package/databases/yourdatabasefile.db`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See below image. it may help you.

[image: DDMS]

Comment: see in above image in file Explorer . data/data/com.navigationsystem/database folder there is any file name "database.db". and one more thing check your code please change your database name private static final String DATABASE_NAME="database.db" or private static final String DATABASE_NAME="navigationsystem.db";

Comment: you must have to select emulator in which you run your app. please select that in Device tab. after that you show file list in File Explorer.