# My Sqlite database icon is not visible in file explorer?

Tags: android-sqlite

[image: i attached my screenshot here]

1.how to create sqlite database in eclipse .

2.My SQLite icon is invisible in File Explorer.

Comment: sqlite database is automatically created when you use it. you have tried some code???  or you want to see your database file then---.http://stackoverflow.com/a/10715631/1168654

Comment: i workout this program http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ ..db file is missing

Comment: you got an error?? or yo have downloaded code from http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: download code from that site run it. insert some data. after that see in DDMS--->file explorar-->data\data\com.mypackagename\database\mydatabase.db

Comment: in that code TABLE_CONTACTS is created know why it not visible in file explorer under the com.androidhive.sqlitdatabasetutorial

Answer (score 0):

### if your are test [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) in **Android Device** then you can't see db file in **FileExplorar**

for Emulator: run that in emulator after that

### go to **DDMS--->File Explorar-->data/data/com.androidhive.androidsqlite/databases/contactsManager**

where `contactsManager` is your database file

[image]

[image]

---

Edited:

[Working with an emulator or device's file system](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html)

DDMS provides a File Explorer tab that allows you to view, copy, and delete files on the device. This feature is useful in examining files that are created by your application or if you want to transfer files to and from the device.

To work with an emulator or device's file system:

In the Devices tab, select the emulator that you want to view the file system for.
To copy a file from the device, locate the file in the File Explorer and click the Pull file button.
To copy a file to the device, click the Push file button on the File Explorer tab.

so, you have to pull file from device. then **download and install sqlitebrowser** after installing open sqliteBrowser. drag and drop your database file in to sqliteBrowser.

Comment: ya contact Manager is not .db extension how it ill be open .if i click that database icon is not lighting y?

Comment: i dowloaded the SQLite jar file i put into the eclipse->dropins folder then only icon is visible in the file explorer , if i clicked .db file then only database icon is lighting  otherwise is not ligthing .u know how to instal sqlite using install new software?

Comment: not an jar file. you have to install sqlitebrowser in your PC.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28504/discussion-between-deepika-and-dhaval-sodha-parmar)